# DataGridView won't show correctly after loading some data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I load data from SQLite to DataGridView. DataGridView doesn't show correctly. I have tried to use follow methods: `Refresh`, `Paint`, `Update`, `Invalidate` DataGridView.

[image]

If I minimize and maximize my program, then DataGridView shows correctly.

[image]

I execute it in the MainForm.

```
private void thicknessComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> tm1Deflection = database.ExecuteSelectQuery(connectionString, tm1ListCommand, parameters);
    List<string> tension = database.ExecuteSelectQuery(connectionString, tensionListCommand, parameters);

    var rowHeaders = new string[] { "TM-1 READING", "SPOKE TENSION (KGF)" };
    var rows = new List<string[]> { tm1Deflection.ToArray(), tension.ToArray() };

    formControl.SetDataGridViewValues(conversionTableGridView, tm1Deflection.Count, rowHeaders, rows); // This string filling DataGridView
}
```

Filling DataGridView locates in another class:

```
public void SetDataGridViewValues(DataGridView dataGridView, int columnCount, string[] rowHeaders, List<string[]> rows)
{
    dataGridView.ColumnCount = columnCount;
    dataGridView.RowHeadersWidth = 165;

    int columnsWidth = (dataGridView.Width - dataGridView.RowHeadersWidth) / dataGridView.ColumnCount;

    for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
    {
        dataGridView.Columns[i].Name = "";
        dataGridView.Columns[i].Width = columnsWidth;
    }

    dataGridView.Rows.Clear();

    if (rows.Count != rowHeaders.Length)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Number of row headers must be equal number of rows!", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView.Rows.Add(rows[i]);
            dataGridView.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = rowHeaders[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Example with DataTable:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(int));
table.Rows.Add(1);
conversionTableGridView.DataSource = table;
```

Error:
[image]

I have clicked on first cell:
[image]

Comment: Your code does not show *when* or *where* it is being executed. My guess: you execute it on your UI thread. Please show us the relevant portions of code, so we see, when you are trying to `Refresh()` and from where, and when and where the grid is being filled.

Comment: You are going to have to provide better details as to what you are wanting to do and what is not working as expected. Whatever you are trying to achieve, it looks like you are taking the most complicated route to get there. Can you explain what the goal of this code is? Why are you adding the rows to the grid manually with… `dataGridView.Rows.Add(rows[i]);` if you have the data from SQLite? I would think that using the data from SQLite could be used as a `DataSource`. Again it is unclear what you are wanting to do.

Comment: I have updated my code. I need to load data from SQLite to DataGridView, when the event ComboBoxTextChanges has triggered.

Comment: I have replaced and tried to execute, but it didn't help me.

Comment: I see `Exception thrown: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' in System.Configuration.dll` in output. Is my problem depend on it?

Comment: When this line of code executes… `var rows = new List<string[]> { tm1Deflection.ToArray(), tension.ToArray() };` rows is a `List<string[]>`… this is may be convenient at this point, however, this `List<string[]>` CAN NOT be used as a `DataSource` to the grid. That is why you are having to “manually” add the rows to the grid.

Comment: I suggest that since you have the two `List<string>` objects `tm1Deflection` and `tension` … that you make a `DataTable` with two rows from those lists of strings instead of a `List<string[]>`. That way you can use the `DataTable` as a `DataSource` to the grid. Then add the row headers to the two rows in the grid.

Comment: @JohnG I have tried to replace `List<string>` follow code:
`DataTable table = new DataTable(); table.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(int)); table.Rows.Add(1);
conversionTableGridView.DataSource = table;`
I have the same error.

Comment: I am not sure what “same” error you are talking about. From the code in the comment, it looks like there is only one column with one row? What error is this code giving you? If you want I can post an example of what I describe.

Comment: @JohnG I have added my example with DataTable to the post. It is a just test. I have problem with painting. I want to get your description.

Comment: Sorry but I am still unable to reproduce what you describe. As you stated that the method `SetDataGridViewValues` is “in another class”… well where is this class `formControl`? Is it a “userControl”? If it is, then what does it look like? We already know that it has a method called `SetDataGridViewValues` that takes a grid and fills it.

Comment: However, this seems like an odd thing for a “UserControl” to do. A simple static method would be better. In addition, If it is a user control, then drawing could be affected. Can you clarify “what” `formControl` is and how it is related to the current form?

Comment: @JohnG `FormControl` isn't a `UserControl`. This class is used to add items to the MainForm. I have tried to add new `DataGridView` to my MainForm (I didn't use FormControl for it), but I had the same painting problem.

Comment: Well, how is the grid `conversionTableGridView` getting added to the form? If the `formControl` class is not adding the grid to the form? Is the grid added to the form in the designer? This is how my tests have been structured and there have been no problems.

Comment: Sorry, but there must be something else going on that you are not providing. Without code that reproduces the problem, using trial and error to reproduce the issue is not something anyone wants to do. I used a `UserControl` and a `static class` and both worked as expected using the posted code.

Comment: I recommend you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You would be surprised how often this simple process will “reveal” the problem you are having. As a bonus, IF, after creating the MRE, the problem still persists, then you will have the code needed to post on “SO” such that others can simply copy/paste the code to reproduce the same problem. Posting incomplete code only forces others to “guess” and speculate. And, worse for you, they will simply move to another question. Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try to reproduce my problem with a MPE.

Comment: @JohnG my problem is only in debug mode. `Exception thrown: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' in System.Configuration.dll`
How is it possible?